# Facing issue while invoking grep inside awk command

Tags: unix, awk, grep

I am looking for extracting some information from log using awk and based on the information returned i want to grep the whole file and write all the output from gerp and awk to a file. I was able to extract few information form awk but while using grep inside awk i am not able to extract information. Please find the logs as follow.

```
2014-04-10 13:55:59,837 [WebContainer : 4] [com.cisco.ata.service.AtAService] WARN  - AtAService::AtAServiceRequest DetailMessage - module=ataservice;service=ataservicerequest;APP_ID=CDCSDSATAUser.gen;VIEW_NAME=/EntitlementView[CCOID="frhocevar"]REQUEST_ID_STRING=-105411838, took 100 milliseconds.
```

Based on the REQUEST_ID_STRING i have to get usecaseID.

```
2014-04-10 13:55:59,800 [Thread-66] [com.cisco.ata.cla.CLAManager] INFO  - CLAManager.getAttributeFromCLAMapping() took 6 ms, for useCaseID - UC41, condition= (CCOID=frhocevar), requestID= -105411838
```

i am extracting REQUEST_ID_STRING using awk but i am not able to extract "useCaseID" using grep.

Below is the command i am using.

```
grep -i -r 'AtAService::AtAServiceRequest DetailMessage - module=ataservice;service=ataservicerequest'  /opt/httpd/logs/apps/atasvc/prod1/was70/*/*.log* |
awk 'BEGIN{count=0;}{if($14>1000){print $0}}' |
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=";"} 
{a = substr($3,8)} 
{b = substr($4,index($4,"/")+1,index($4,"]R")-index($4,"/"))} 
{c = substr($4,index($4,"G=")+2,index($4,", took")-index($4,"G=")-2);}
{d = substr($1,0,index($1,":")-1)} 
{e=grep command which will extract usecaseid from $d having file name} 
{ print a","b","c","d","e} '
```

Comment: I don't see the need for embedding a grep cmd here. Basically `awk` is grep on super-steroids. And you don't have to be cute with regexps. Try `e=$0; sub(/.*REQUEST_ID_STRING=/, "",e); sub(/ *$/, "", e);e = "RequestID= "e ;`. Also, stop using commas to separate your output values. Using tabs or `|` chars avoids (99.999% of the time) a whole class of error involving embedded `,' chars in data. Good luck.

Comment: You seem to be making this much more difficult for yourself than it really is. Post a FEW lines of sample input plus your expected output and clarify which file(s) the input is in and what exactly you're searching for in each.

Answer (score 2):

This uses some basic "awkisms" that make for some pretty good boilerplate starting points for a lot of stuff.

```
AirBoxOmega:~ d$ cat log
2014-04-10 13:55:59,837 [WebContainer : 4] [com.cisco.ata.service.AtAService] WARN - AtAService::AtAServiceRequest DetailMessage - module=ataservice;service=ataservicerequest;APP_ID=CDCSDSATAUser.gen;VIEW_NAME=/EntitlementView[CCOID="frhocevar"]REQUEST_ID_STRING=-105411838, took 100 milliseconds.
2014-04-10 13:55:59,800 [Thread-66] [com.cisco.ata.cla.CLAManager] INFO - CLAManager.getAttributeFromCLAMapping() took 6 ms, for useCaseID - UC41, condition= (CCOID=frhocevar), requestID= -105411838
AirBoxOmega:~ d$ cat stackHelp.awk

     {
        if ($0 ~ /AtAService::AtAServiceRequest DetailMessage/ && $(NF - 1) > 99) {
            split($0, tmp, "[-,]")
            slow[tmp[7]]++
    }
        if (slow[substr($NF,2)]) {
            split($0, tmp, "[-,]")
            print $NF tmp[8]
    }
}

AirBoxOmega:~ d$ gawk -f stackHelp.awk log
-105411838 UC41
```

This uses a pretty basic awk concept where if you know that there is something common among your log lines (a sessionID, or some such) you create an array for that based on certain conditions (in this case that the log line contains a given string and that the next to last column is > 99). Then later when you run into that same sessionID, you can check to see if an array exists for it, and if so, pull out even more info.

You may need/want to add something to the second if statement so it's only checking log lines you care about, but honestly, awk is so fast that it probably won't matter. (I'm using gawk [via brew] as the version of awk that comes with OSX is somewhat lacking, but this code is basic enough that awk or gawk should work.)

If you need a better explanation of the code, I'll try to explain better.

Ninja edit: Few quit tips:

- Don't use `grep -i` unless you really don't know the case you're looking for. Case insensitivity will make your searches MUCH slower
- If you're not using any kind of regular expressions, use `fgrep` instead of `grep`. It's much faster out the box.